# How to align ImageButtons in a layout evenly

Tags: android, android-xml, android-imagebutton

I currently have 4 `ImageButton`s in a layout that takes only half of the screen height. I would like the `ImageButton`s to be placed evenly in the layout. Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This works, since here is the result:

[image]

The issue is, 1: I would like to add text under each button and I am not sure how that is going to work and 2: the white spots to the right and left of the `ImageButton`s are active, as if they were parts of the button. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can put your ImageButton along with a TextView within a FrameLayout

Comment: "They are active" because it is the button. You have set a background image of a certain size and "0dp" with layout_weight = "1" to the ImageButtons (which makes extending "intelligently"). You can try to put "wrap_content" to your buttons or its wrapper and work with margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (and better) alternative is to work with TableLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Text 1"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Text 2"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Text 3"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/feed_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Text 4"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Wow! Although the other answer was good, your answer is great! I love how I have absolutely NO warning messages with your code. Thank you very much!!

Comment: It's my pleasure. (;

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/section1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="info 1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="info 2"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="info 3"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="info 4"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

and for second part of question you should set click listener on entire relative layout. for example for tap on first cell :-

xml

```
 android:id="@+id/section1"
```

JAVA

> findviewbyid(R.id.section1).setOnClickListener(...)